# Access Tomcat folders on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an EC2 instance with the AWS provided Tomcat server environment.
How do I access Tomcat folders on this instance?
I need to check the contents of the default server.xml which resides inside Tomcat.
I know the path of the server.xml, But I need to know how to access it from my local system.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [ssh](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-deploy-app.html) into your EC2 instance and navigate to your tomcat installation.

If you've done a default Tomcat installation, the main folder will be `/etc/tomcat{version}`. You can review here for more details about files and folders

## make sure to create [an EC2 key pair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-prereq.html#create-a-key-pair)

## If you're using Windows: You'll need [putty](http://www.putty.org/)

1. Start PuTTY (from the Start menu, click All Programs > PuTTY > PuTTY).
2. In the Category pane, select Session and complete the following fields:

a. In Host Name, enter `ec2-user@public_dns_name`.

b. Ensure that Port is 22.

[image]

3. In the Category pane, under Connection type, expand SSH, and then select Auth. Complete the following:

a. Click Browse.

b. Select the .ppk file that you generated for your key pair, as described in Create a Key Pair, and then click Open.

c. Click Open to start the PuTTY session.

4. If this is the first time you have connected to this instance, PuTTY displays a security alert dialog box that asks whether you trust the host you are connecting to. Click Yes. A window opens and you are connected to your instance.

## To connect to your instance from Linux or Mac OS X using SSH

1. Use the ssh command to connect to the instance. You'll specify the private key (.pem) file and ec2-user@public_dns_name.

   $ ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com

You'll see a response like the following.

```
The authenticity of host 'ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com (10.254.142.33)'
can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 1f:51:ae:28:bf:89:e9:d8:1f:25:5d:37:2d:7d:b8:ca:9f:f5:f1:6f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Enter `yes.

You'll see a response like the following.

```
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (RSA) 
to the list of known hosts.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Frédéric Henri.
I have followed this process and I am able to ssh the instance too.
How can I traverse through the folders?
May I know what commands I can use and get to the specific location of Tomcat?

Comment: use `cd` to change directory so `cd /etc/tomcat{version}` but if you know nothing about linux usage, you should find yourself a book or a good tutorial

Comment: I do know basic commands. So to list all the contents, i did run "ls" but that did not display anything.

Comment: what exactly did you do ? (all steps) you can use `ls -all` to see if you have hidden files

Comment: AWS EC2 generates a .pem key file, not .ppk. So you need to use PuTTy to convert pem to ppk: https://linuxacademy.com/guide/17385-use-putty-to-access-ec2-linux-instances-via-ssh-from-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ssh` into the server. You can do that through your local system or throw AWS console by clicking `connect` after selecting an instance the ec2 instances menu

for details on how to `ssh`: 
[link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html#ec2-connect-to-instance-linux)